# Woocommerce Persistant Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am tasked with setting Contacts to an organization within Woocommerce. Each Organization will have its own user account within Worpdress but contacts are stored in user meta, so contacts do not have a WP user account.

When a contact of an organization logs in, the organization session is passed back to the contact using wp_set_auth_cookie.

The issue I am facing is if multiple contacts are shopping for the organization at the same time then each contact keeps sharing each others carts.

For example;

Contact A - adds product 1 ONLY

Contact B - adds product 2 ONLY

When both carts get refreshed, both contacts see product 1 and 2.

I have had a quick look around, and came across something within WC called persistant cart.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_persistent_cart_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

I have tried the above filter, but carts are still being shared regardless. In a nutshell, I want contacts carts being stored locally rather than within the database although the same user account is being used.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks

Comment: Still unable to find a solution for this. It seem's as though persistant cart is still enabled?

Comment: Still unable to resolve this. I have tried the above filter again but still have the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The persistent cart in WooCommerce (which is rightly disabled using the filter you mentioned above `woocommerce_persistent_cart_enabled`) stores the cart to **user meta**. This ensures the cart is preserved if the current cart session expires (either by logging out or after a certain period of time).

The problem you are facing is that sessions for logged-in users store the current user ID (customer ID), and this ID is then used to store/retrieve the cart from the database.

What I think you'd need to do, if separate user accounts are not possible, is create a new class that extends the Session handler (`WC_Session_Handler`).

The session class can be filtered:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_session_handler', 'WC_Session_Handler' )
```

`WC_Session_Handler` is the default.

In your custom `WC_Session_Handler`, change the method that defines the customer ID so that it takes your contact into consideration. e.g.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $customer_id = strval( get_current_user_id() );
}
```

Would become:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $customer_id = strval( get_current_user_id() ) . '_your_contact_id';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked perfectly, It was a nightmare trying to suss out what needed changing and what needed keeping but I managed to resolve this;